# Struggling with responsive Background-Image

Tags: html, css, image, background-image

I have read so many posts about responsive CSS Background-Image's but I can't make mine work.

My site is http://www.conn3cted.uk.tn/intManagement.html and I'm trying to use the image as a 'banner' so can't have the height too large.

I seem to be able to fix the issue either on Desktop or Mobile, but they don't want to work together. I've used the suggested solutions (below) but I don't get the whole picture to scale up/down and it only shows part of it or a lot of white space. What am I doing wrong!?

```
.whatWeDo {
  padding-top: 100px;
  background-image: url("/images/intManagement/homePage/whatwedo.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 120px;
}
```

Comment: Try to use `margin-top` instead of `padding-top`

Comment: check out this link for responsive Images https://responsivedesign.is/resources/images/picture-fill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this css and use media queries to change your margin-top for mobile device:

```
.whatWeDo {
    background-image: url("/images/intManagement/homePage/whatwedo.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    height: 100vh;
    margin-top: 80px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 878px) {
  .whatWeDo {
        margin-top: 170px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah that's even better! As I can make it work with the iPad as well! Could you explain to me what `100vh` is please? I've only ever worked with `px` or `%` when dealing with `height` etc

Comment: vh is a viewport unit, the viewport is the area where the browser renders the site.

vw: 1/100th viewport width
vh: 1/100th viewport height
vmin: 1/100th of the smallest side
vmax: 1/100th of the largest side
Note: IE9 uses vm instead of vmin. It does not support vmax.

Comment: I think I need to do some reading - still confused about what it is :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this css with replace your css:

This can also responsive only set top as per you needed:

```
.whatWeDo {
  background-image: url("/images/intManagement/homePage/whatwedo.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I slightly amended it (I removed the `padding-top` as it didn't appear to be needed and amended `height:` to `30%` as it was was too large. But thanks to you it's perfect! Would you give me a brief explanation of what this is all doing please?

Comment: Because your ".navbar" class give position:fixed then i give the position:relative  in this class".whatWeDo"